# Cycling through pages without a full page refresh using AJAX, pushState, jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pushstate

I am working on a Rails project where I have numerous short Posts, and I would like to add navigation links (next and previous) to allow users to cycle through the posts.

However, I would like to do this **asynchronously**, which is where I'm running into trouble - **I just don't know where to begin** (I AM A NOOB).

I've been looking at various combinations of pushState, AJAX and jQuery, all to no avail. I feel like there must be a simple solution to this problem, but I'm not sure at this point.

**For an example of this, you can check out: http://www.brotips.ru/76/** - the left and right nav arrows.

I'm not asking for a full solution (of course this would be great), but rather a push in the right direction.

Thanks a lot in advance.